# How exactly error ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError works with angular detection?

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I read a lot of articles but still don't understand some cases with angular change detection. I got following example :
Angular app with OnInit, AfterViewInit, DoCheck, AfterViewChecked implemented in all components:

1. Parent
2. Child
3. DeepChild

Only in parent I got popular loading example implemented (and `*ngIf="isLoading"` in HTML):

```
export class AppComponent
  implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, DoCheck, AfterViewChecked
{
  isLoading = false;
  constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.isLoading = true;
    console.log('parent - after view init');
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    console.log('AFTER CHECK');
  }

  ngDoCheck(): void {
    console.log('parent - do check');
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('parent - init');
    
  }
}
```

Output (without loading `this.isLoading = true;`) is :

```
parent - init
parent - do check
Child - init
Child - do check
DeepChild - init
DeepChild - do check
DeepChild - after view init
DeepChild - after check
Child - after view init
Child - after check
parent - after view init
parent - after view check
<with assigning loading value as in code above here I got expression changed error>
<and after that I got some more checks generated>
parent - do check
Child - do check
DeepChild - do check
DeepChild - after check
Child - after check
parent - after check
```

I got following questions :

1. Why I got this additional checks?
2. If I add loading I got error `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`, I understand that this is after view is checked but I got this additional checks so why issue still exist?
3. If I will add changeDetectorRef and manually do detect changes, problem is resolved, but why? Okey, I trigger next detection, but in privies one expression has still been changed after check, so why trigerring next one just resolve it?
4. This detectChanges only triggers `doCheck` in child components.. despite of fact that I trigger it in parent component it's not calling detection in parent?

Answer (score 0):

You want uni-directional data flow in your applications. During the component life cycle angular renders data from parent down to child. Angular has a development check so that after the whole view is rendered in that cycle it goes ahead and runs the whole rendering of data from parent down to child *to ensure nothing changed*. In production this 2nd check won't run and the data that changed won't be rendered as having changed in that detection cycle.

If you set `isLoading = false;` and the parent is rendered and then you change that value just after, you've broken this uni-directional data flow. The children will get rendered with `isLoading = false;` despite you changing this after. Forcing change detection to run twice on the parent "solves" the issue because the parent will be rendered with the updated value which will work in production. But it's an anti-pattern to throw in detection cycles to fix bad data flow.

I've never used `ngDoCheck` in any code over 4 years of Angular, I wouldn't recommend spending a long trying to understand it.

Comment: thanks for answer , but still no answer for my questions, I'm trying to undestarand that issue deeper, and also understand why there are some additinional checks <are this checks comes from fact, that this was runned in development mode maybe>, and why there is no issue when I will run change detection? previous change detection still should cause an issue...

Comment: Yes 2 round of checks are the dev checks (you can run locally as production config to compare)

Comment: are You sure? error is throwed before second check... it should be thrower after second <correct me if Im wrong of course>